# SELECT unique row from field 3 to field 4

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forms

Is there a way to delete duplicate records based on two fields?

I have a system where people can register for sport events. In the table:

event_registrations
• unique_id
• eventname
• id (person's id number)
• Name and Surname

One person can apply for many events - id may duplicate
an event may have multiple participants - eventname may duplicate:

```
--Johnsmith--  --Mountain Cycle--
--Johnsmith--  --Marathnon Walk--

--Linda--      --Mountain Cycle--
--Johnsmith--  --Mountain Cycle--
```

But a person may not register for a event they have already registered for:

```
--Johnsmith--   --Mountain Cycle--
--Johnsmith--   --Mountain Cycle--
```

They Select a event name through a form. Then the form data and their user details is stored in table event_registrations.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You could forbid that by adding a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(eventname,personid)`

Comment: how do i add one to the combination of the field?

Comment: @SebastianOpperman - Also, if you already have a `Person` table that you can reference, _that_ table should contain the `name` and `surname` column, and it should be removed from the `event_registrations` table (and I recommend remaning `id` to `person_id`, to make the source obvious).  Oh, and you should probably create an `event` table, and store a foreign key to that, not a name - what happens when someone enters the correct spelling for 'Marathon', for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First delete any rows with duplicate `(eventname, id)` combinations.

Then add the UNIQUE constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable
  ADD CONSTRAINT eventname_person_Unique
    UNIQUE INDEX eventname_id_U 
       (eventname, id) ;
```

Your form that adds registrations should be adjusted accordingly to treat the error it will get from MySQL when a duplicate row is rejected.

Answer (score 0):

A `UNIQUE INDEX` is the way to prevent this, as ypercube suggests. To identify/delete existing duplicates you could use this:

```
SELECT
    eventname,
    id    -- You should consider using a less ambiguous name here
FROM
    Event_Registrations ER1
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Event_Registrations ER2
        WHERE
            ER2.eventname = ER1.eventname AND
            ER2.id = ER1.id AND
            (ER2.registration_datetime < ER1.registration_datetime OR
                (ER2.registration_datetime = ER1.registration_datetime AND
                 ER2.unique_id < ER1.unique_id
                )
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do some data tidy up before adding the unique constraint then you could use the following (one good reason why always having a unique id column is a good idea):

```
create table id_for_deletion (id int unsigned not null);

insert into id_for_deletion (id) 
( 
select a.delete_me_id
from (
select eventname,id,max(unique_id) as delete_me_id
from event_registrations
group by eventname,id
having count(*) > 1
) a);



delete from event_registrations where unique_id in (select id from id_for_deletion);

drop table id_for_deletion;
```